# Getting error on JMETER: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Getting this below mentioned error, on execution with 1 Thread User:

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake
[image]

Comment: I am trying using jmeter, and no config element is there for User-Agent header

Comment: It is already added
User-Agent 
Value=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.54 Safari/537.36
Do I need to check SSL Certificate, but it is not working with JMeter only, and normally on browsers the site is working fine

Comment: Do I need to make some changes in JMETER Properties for this

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a [TLS protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Transport_Layer_Security) mismatch, you need to identify which protocol the server is using and then configure JMeter to use the same protocol.

You can enable debug logging for the HTTPS connections by adding the next line to *system.properties* file:

```
javax.net.debug=all
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up.

and then inspect JMeter console ([STDOUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout))) to see what does server respond to JMeter's [handshakes](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/7.5?topic=ssl-overview-tls-handshake) and depending on the outcome amend JMeter's configuration (again using [system or JMeter properties](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)) so JMeter's TLS protocol would match the server's one.

More information: [Debugging SSL/TLS Connections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html)

Comment: Enabled protocols: [TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
.JsseSSLManager: Using default SSL protocol: TLS
SSLConnectionSocketFactory: Starting handshake
2022-06-16 15:45:02,095 DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection: http-outgoing-2: Shutdown connection
2022-06-16 15:45:02,095 DEBUG o.a.h.i.e.MainClientExec: Connection discarded

Comment: Application is using TLS 1.2 and TLS 1.3
Now need to add it in system or JMeter properties?